# After adding .7z mimetype to IIS server .jpg stopped to show up on the site with 500

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019, mime-type

I've added .7z mime type with text/plain to my IIS server on Windows Server 2019.
After that site's web.config was added the block (I didn't do that)

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".7z" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

And the most interesting that after that site is loading all text and css but not the images giving 500 error on them.

1. Why this block was added to my web.config?
2. Why on earth it stopped to show only images?

*was tested in Firefox cache disabled

Comment: Question 3: Why do you want `text/plain` for a binary format? Question 4: What does your logs show?

Comment: Adding to vidarlo's comment, application/octet-stream is way too broad. Any binary file is octet-stream eventually, apparently images like jpg, png, etc are included also. application/x-7z-compressed it the mime type for 7z files, at least that's what I get on my computer.

Comment: I think something else causes the 500 errors, which you can trace out with FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing